# How to enable 3D acceleration with an Nvidia Geforce GT 540M

Tags: 3d, hardware-acceleration

I have NVIDIA Geforce GT 540M. I have a problem with "3D acceleration".
Every game I install tells me "you don't have 3D acceleration". What can I do to enable 3D acceleration on my computer?

Comment: Probably you haven't installed the proprietary Graphics card driver for Nvidia cards

Comment: You should look similar answers regarding Optimus technology: you won't be able to use NVidia card unless you use something like Bumblebee or IronHide.

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work

Answer (score 2):

the GT 540M indicates that you have optimus technology. Optimus allows you to choose between the Intel GPU that is part of the Core i Series processors and the discrete chip (the Nvidia GT 540M).

There are two things I would do:

Check your bios settings and see if you can set the video card to use the discrete graphics only. This is not available on all bioses, but if it is there you will have the options of:

> Optimus
>
> Discrete
>
> Integrated

Choose Discrete.

Then upon completing the boot ensure the Nvidia proprietary drivers are installed. There should be no need to use the PPA; simply use

> System Settings > Additional Drivers

That should then give you options for your Nvidia card.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
http://www.geforce.com/drivers/
Select your Model (GT 500M Series)
Select OS: Linux (32/64 bit)
Download linux drivers, run it and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

did you install proprietary driver? you can use this ppa to install latest(currently 290.10) nvidia driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers nvidia-settings
```

Comment: hmm it dosn't work :(

E: Impossible de trouver le paquet nvidia-graphics-drivers

Comment: use this command with net connection enabled (omit the last one), then use additional diveer apps (search it in dash) or search "nvidia" either in software center or synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Dell 1510 and I added the xorg-edgers ppa.  I have no idea if it will work for you, but if you have ppa-purge installed then its worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have two laptop. The first one is DELL vostro 1510 with GeForce 8400 M GS grapghic card. The second one is DELL XPS with GeForce GT 540 M. I have solved the problem of the first one using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aaron-haviland/cuda-4.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

But I cannot find a good repository for the second one.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at switcheroo or acpi-call in order to solve hybrid graphics card problems. google will help.